# Problems with manipulating divs within simplemodal dialog popup - Further Edit

Tags: javascript, jquery, simplemodal

Ok, I'm having a major headache with simplemodal - I know I'm almost there, but can't get this to quite work right.  I have a simplemodal dialog that has several dynamically created divs inside it, such as

```
<html>
<head>
<!-- Confirm CSS files -->
<link type='text/css' href='css/confirm.css' rel='stylesheet' media='screen' />
</head>

<body>
<div id='container'>
<h1>Test Page</h1>
<div id='content'>
    <div id='confirm-dialog'>
        Page Content Goes Here
    </div>

<!-- modal content -->
<div id='confirm'>
   <div class='header'><span>Header Text</span></div>
   <div class='message'>
     <div id='optionDiv0'><input type='radio' id='options' name='options' value='0' />Option0</div>
     <div id='optionDiv1'><input type='radio' id='options' name='options' value='1' />Option1</div>
     <div id='optionDiv2'><input type='radio' id='options' name='options' value='2' />Option2</div>
   </div>
   <div class='buttons'>
     <div class='yes'>OK</div>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Load JavaScript files -->
<script type='text/javascript' src='scripts/jquery.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='scripts/jquery.simplemodal.js'></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function ($) {
$('#confirm-dialog input.confirm, #confirm-dialog a.confirm').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    confirm("", function () {
        for(var k = 0; k <= 3; k++) {
            if(options[k].checked) {
            var ele = document.getElementById("optionDiv" + k);
            ele.style.display = "none;";
            //alert("Stop Here");
            }
        }

        });
});
});

function confirm(message, callback) {
$('#confirm').modal({
    closeHTML: "<a href='#' title='Close' class='modal-close'>x</a>",
    position: ["20%",],
    overlayId: 'confirm-overlay',
    containerId: 'confirm-container', 
    containerCss: {
                        height: 300,
                        width: 450,
                        backgroundColor: '#fff',
                        border: '3px solid #ccc'
                  },

    onShow: function (dialog) {
        var modal = this;

        $('.message', dialog.data[0]).append(message);

        // if the user clicks "yes"
        $('.yes', dialog.data[0]).click(function () {
            // call the callback
            if ($.isFunction(callback)) {
                callback.apply();
            }
            // close the dialog
            modal.close(); // or $.modal.close();
        });
    }
});
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

In the click code, I'm trying to make it so when the user clicks on one of the radio buttons, then clicks 'OK', that item is no longer visible in the popup. If I follow that code with an `alert("Stop here");`(shown in the code above, commented out), then I can see the div disappear from the popup. But once I clear the alert box, (or if I comment it out so it never runs), the next time I activate the dialog, the div that I hid is re-appearing. How can I keep it hidden, so that it remains hidden the next time the dialog is activated, or is that possible?  Thanks in advance.

FINAL EDIT: Found the solution for the dialog box reverting to its original state every time it opens. I pasted this in just above the jquery code, and it works like a charm:

```
<script> $.modal.defaults.persist = true; </script>
```

Found on this site in another thread, as part of a different question. Thanks for all who helped.

Comment: There is no way to answer your question without seeing your code. It's a waste of time in the current state. :(

Comment: I showed the code that is applicable, I don't think anyone really wants to see the entire page that this is on. I pared it down for brevity. Is there something specific missing that causes you to think it's a waste of time?

Comment: Just think, you show us a HTML and one valid line that hide an element. It looks fine. the problems is somewhere else. I can't tell you where is the problem, but it's not here.

Comment: Edited the code for clarification

Comment: Why are you intermingling jQuery and `document.getElementById`?  Where is `options` defined?

Comment: options is defined in the simplemodal div for the popup. I'm using document.getElementById, because that is what's been working for me to get the element that I want to hide. I'm using it on other pages for purposes such as setting values, getting values, and so forth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code still doesn't look complete to me, but as for your `confirm` function callback

```
confirm("", function(){
    $('#confirm input[type=radio]').each(function(){
        if($(this).is(':checked'))
            $(this).parent().empty();
    });
});
```

Like that?

Comment: Not quite - I changed the 'checkbox' to 'radio', since they are radio buttons. This hides the checked radio button, but not its associated text - and as soon as the dialog is cleared, the next time it's opened, the radio button is back in its original state. I'm wanting it (and its text) to stay gone for the next time the dialog is opened.

Comment: I believe that's what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: By the way, the solution you presented did remove the item - but it still came back the next time the dialog opened. But I found a solution in another question that when combined with yours, does exactly what I was after - Above the JQuery code, I added the following:

Comment: <script>
        $.modal.defaults.persist = true;
    </script>

Comment: Glad that worked. You might add that to your original post for future eyes. :)